# Send Firebase notifications to topic based on language

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I need to send Firebase notifications to a topic based on the device/user language. So, for example, a notification should be sent to all devices with English language subscribed to the topic "news".

Am I right, that this is not possible using the Firebase Console? Is there another way except creating language specific topics (e.g. "news-en", "news-fr", ...)?

Many thanks!

Comment: nope you need language specific tags like you suggest

Comment: @tyczj You should add that in as an answer. :)

Comment: All right! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I recently run into this issue also, and maybe found some workaround, maybe workable for you.

Currently the firebase console can pick a language to push, but the doc says that the language base on the device, but according to my survey, I still can not find the relation yet.

So, I suggest you can add the valuable in the customize key/value, and extend FirebaseMessagingService

Override the function of handleIntent, to get the key/value which you want.

The before push your customize notification, clear all notification of your application, after that, you will receive your customize notification. In this case, you can also customize the notification based on the device display language.